# How to load a App.Config file into a VCL application?

Tags: wpf, delphi, dll, plugins, app-config

[image]

I am trying the [RemObject Hydra](http://hydra.remobjects.com/hydra/) to embed a WPF module inside a VCL app.

In this WPF module, I have Grid Controls, and EntityFramework DataContext. It's `connectionString`, `providers` and everything stored in a `app.config`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ModelConnection" connectionString="character set=UTF8;data source=localhost;initial catalog=PATHTODATABASE.FDB;user id=SYSDBA;password=MASTERKEY" providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" publicKeyToken="3750abcc3150b00c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
            <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data></configuration>
```

The next step was to make the VCL host with delphi then load the WPF module's .dll using the `HYModuleManager` component. This is pretty straigtforward :

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    HYModuleManager1.LoadModule('%path%\to\wpf\module\GridsModule.dll');
    HYModuleManager1.CreateVisualPlugin('ClientGridView', fInstance, Panel1);
end;
```

I run the application in Delphi. But this error is thrown :

[image: An exception was thrown by the target of an invocation]

**(Translation : An exception was thrown by the target of an invocation)**

So with a little more research, I run this application (HydraHost.exe) using VisualStudio, and realize that this si the exception thrown by the module :

```
System.InvalidOperationException : 'No connection string named 'ModelConnection' could be found in the application config file.'
```

I then decide to write a **WPF host**. I set the WPF Host App.config to include the connection string and provider infos. To no surprise, everything works fine.

[image]

So, with the VCL host, the connectionString is not found. With the WPF host, it is. My conclusion is that the app.config is not loaded by the VCL host but it is loaded by the WPF host.

So what I did next is to manually copy the WPFHost.dll.config to VCLHost.exe.config as suggested by one of the answers, but same error, connectionString is not found.

So my question is : How can I "link" a .exe.config to a VCL app built with Delphi?

Comment: Maybe you could try to read configuration settings/connection string directly from config file using ConfigurationManager https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134260(v=vs.110).aspx
It could give you more detailed error of it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your app.config to YourExeName.exe.config as it's probably now YourDllName.dll.config

Comment: Yes I tried this already, but it seems it is not loaded. I still get the MyConnectionString not found error... Are you sure delphi VCL exes will try to find the .exe.config?

Comment: Vcl exe knows nothing about config files, but .net ConfigurationManager loads executable config file. We are also using hydra to load .net assembly to our vcl exe. Though we are not using config files to automatic configuration options, we read few appSettings from there.